# Fieldset Top Border breaks after changing the background color of Input field present in it: Only in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, fieldset

**Update**

I am facing an issue with fieldset top border in IE 11.

Description:
I am having a fieldset in my web page. Its legend tag contains a checkbox. And its sub elements are input text fields. I have a JS which changes background color of input fields on checking/Unchecking checkbox present in legend.

Problem:
When background color of input field changes, Fieldset's top border breaks

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Sample Code:

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.getElementById("changeit").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
table .td-left {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
}

table .td-right {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="changeBackground()">
    <label>Hello</label>
  </legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-right">
        <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-left">
        <input type="text" id="changeit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please provide a working example (maybe using https://codepen.io/ or an image of the problem since it is a graphic issue) because I wasn't able to reproduce described behaviour. Your snippet works on my computer using Internet Explorer 11.345.17134.0

Comment: I also try to make a test but not able to produce the issue with your above posted code. As other community member suggested you. you need to provide an example that can produce the issue. Then we can try to provide any solution or work around for it.

Comment: Check the updated version for sample code

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra

Comment: Still can't reproduce your issue, this is what I see with your cose on Internet Explorer 11.354 --> [link](https://pasteboard.co/HKFfUYz.png)
As you see the border is the same with enabled or disabled checkbox.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra I think JS is not applied in your case as background color is still same for the input box... When you will open the document in browser, a popup will arise asking to allow blocked content or not. Please allow it by selecting "Allow Blocked Content" and then try enabling/disabling the checkbox

Comment: ----- @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: @PrakharJain I can tell if the browser is executing JavaScript or not, the code is the same as you posted, and I created a working example for you -> [view on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kokanuk/edit?html,css,js,output), I can't see the problem with Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10.

Please provide a working example (as I suggested on first comment) if you want people to help you.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra I think their is a slight misunderstanding between us and that is because I used wrong words to describe my issue and I am really very very sorry for that. By enabling/disabling I meant Checking/Unchecking checkbox. The issue is simple that when I change Background color of input box on clicking checkbox using JS, the top border of fieldset breaks. And the code I have mentioned is the exact working sample of the issue I am talking about. You just click on the checkbox and you can see that happen.It is also reproduced in your sample of JSBin. Once again I am really sorry.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand what the problem is. When you apply a background color to an input field the border of that element looks slightly different. If you want to have the same border you have to explicitly declare a style for it, something like this: `input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}`

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra I have updated my Question in a simplified form, I think it will help you understand the problem. And regarding your suggestion for adding css: input[type=text] { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; }:  I have a problem with fieldset's top border, not with input's border. Read my updated version of question and it will make things clearer for you. And also Thanks for responding me regularly, I really appreciate that :)

Comment: Please help me .. I am not able to find any solution till now

Comment: @PrakharJain I cannot reproduce your issue - fieldset's border looks the same no matter if checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra FYI it should be `input[type="text"]` (text in quotes)

Comment: @barbsan which revision of IE11 are you using?

Comment: @PrakharJain v11.345.17134.0

Comment: can you share the screenshots? @barbsan

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/q1Nnfq9 from jsbin linked in comments (only background color became lighter when I focused Output tab) - looks similar for embedded snippet

Comment: @barbsan okay thanks for trying to help:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the checkbox in the legend, obviously. Simply removing the checkbox from the legend makes it work fine.

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.getElementById("changeit").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
table .td-left {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
}

table .td-right {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
  </legend>
  <div style="color:green; height:0; overflow:visible">Booh Booh Booh Booh Booh Booh Booh</div>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="changeBackground()">
  <label>Hello</label>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-right">
        <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-left">
        <input type="text" id="changeit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

So what we need to do is make it *look* like the checkbox is in the legend, without it actually being in there. How about this:

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.getElementById("changeit").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
table .td-left {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
}

table .td-right {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}

fieldset label[for='flip']::before {
  content: ' ☐ ';
}

#flip {
  display: none;
}

#flip:checked+fieldset label[for='flip']::before {
  content: ' ☑ ';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="flip" onclick="changeBackground()">
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <label for="flip">Hello</label>
  </legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-right">
        <label>Enter Text Here:</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-left">
        <input type="text" id="changeit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mr Lister. But I am looking for the cause of this problem..why is this happening? Is this the limitation of IE? Or is their any mistake in my code?What problem is caused by checkbox?

Comment: At first I thought there might be a problem with having interactive content in  the legend, but such a restriction does not exist. So I'm pretty sure it's a bug in IE. Would "Bug in IE" by itself have been enough of an answer to satisfy you?

Comment: Actually I am working on a web application which contains multiple web pages having checkbox in legend tag of fieldset. But surprisingly, this issue is not occurring in one of my web pages, while others are having this issue. Comparing web pages while debugging didn't helped me. But this concludes that this is not a bug in IE as one of my web page is working fine. @Mr Lister

Comment: @PrakharJain Can you provide a link to the page where it doesn't go wrong?

Comment: No its not possible due to confidential reasons